# Books to learn principal bundle, associated bundle, density bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, differential-forms

Are there any books other than Jeffrey Lee's "Manifolds and Differential Geometry" and "Heat kernels and Dirac operators" and Loring Tu's "Differential Geometry" to learn principal, associated, line and density bundles and vector-valued forms?

Jeffrey Lee's book has too many errors and the other two books are hard for me.

I have studied "Introduction to smooth manifolds" and "Riemannian manifolds" by John Lee.

Comment: Kobayashi & Nomizu, David Bleecker's Gauge Theories and Variational Principles (here the subject matter is physics-y, but this is nontheless a mathematics book), vol II. from Spivak's DG books, Michor & Kolár & Slovák: Natural Operations in Differential Geometry (I hope I spelt the authors' name right). These should get you started.

Comment: Another book that I like for these subjects is Walter Poor's _Differential Geometric Structures_.

Comment: "Heat kernels and Dirac operators" is the title of a book by Berline, Getzler and Vergne, did you mean this one?